# Copy formula through columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am using the row() function in excel cell like this way
= ROW()

First question : Why this does not evaluate to the real row number and the cell maintain the "= ROW()" text
Second question : If i try to copy the cell content(in this case the "=ROW()") to the rest of column cells , the text "= ROW()" is maintained like this way

```
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
=ROW()
```

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: So you're seeing `=Row()` in the cell, instead of the row number? Quick test: Press `CTRL` + `~` . That should switch to the regular view.  `=Row()` will grab the row number of the current cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are having one of two issues (or both):

(1) The cells are formatted as text.  Change the formatting to general or a number format.  Then select the first formula cell, click into the formula bar, and press enter.  It should start returning the row number.  Copy that cell down.

(2) If your formula starts with ' (an apostrophe) then the formula is evaluated as text and the output will be the text of the formula and not the row number.

Lastly, if that doesn't seem to do it, make sure your workbook is updated.  If you have manual updates on you may need to manually tell Excel to recalculate all formulas.